# Horizontal scroll appears only in iphone when base64 image added

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Horizontal scroll appears once i upload base64 image using angularjs in a responsive html page and embed in img tag dynamically.
It's working perfectly fine on every device except iphone device portrait mode only (working fine on landscap mode).
I have also used viewport to avoid horizontal scroll.
I have tried almost everything available in css including inline css on image and it's parent div but nothing seems to work for me.

```css
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.upload_image_gallery {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 470px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.upload_image_gallery img {
    max-width: 80px;
    max-height: 50px;
    margin: 5px 10px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.upload_image_gallery .upload_image_item {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    float: left;
}

.upload_image_gallery i.fa-close {
    color: #fff;
    background: #a94442;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    font-size: 11px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 2px;
    top: -5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="upload_image_gallery">
        <div class="upload_image_item" ng-repeat='image in images'>
            <i class="fa fa-close" ng-click="remove_gallery_img($index)"></i>
            <img ng-show="image" ng-src="{{ image.resized.dataURL}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was **canvas size**, Once i scale down the size of canvas's width to 250px after converting image to base64 horizontal scroll issue resolved.

```js
var limit_val = 250;
var cust_ratio = Math.min(limit_val / width, limit_val / height);

if (width > height) {
    if (width > limit_val) {
        width = limit_val;
        height = height * cust_ratio;
    }
} else {
    if (height > limit_val) {
        height = limit_val;
        width = width * cust_ratio;
    }
}


canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(origImage, 0, 0, width, height);
return canvas.toDataURL(type, quality);
```

In-order to get actual size of image i had to create separate function to retain original size so that i can send it to api.